# How to populate a radio button in laravel by using form::model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am populating a radio button by using `form::model` in laravel. The populate form is in blade php. Why is the radio button not populating automatically like the textarea, textbox and drop down list?

```
{{ Form::model($teacher, array('route'=> array('updateteacher', $teacher->id))) }}
{{ Form::label('gender', 'Enetr your gender') }}
{{ Form::label('male', 'Male') }}
{{ Form::radio('gender', 'male') }} 
{{ Form::label('famle', 'Female') }}
{{ Form::radio('gender', 'female', $teacher->gender==1) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I'm working in laravel 4.2, the table name is `teacher` and column name is `gender`.

Comment: When using `Form::model`, be sure to close your form with `Form::close`. Is there an error or something? Can you give some more information about what is going wrong?

Comment: Suggestion: use a question mark in your question to avoid attracting close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the correct syntax is like `($teacher->gender == 'male')` which is in your case:

```
{{ Form::model($teacher, array('route'=> array('updateteacher', $teacher->id))) }}
{{ Form::label('gender', 'Enter your gender') }}
{{ Form::label('male', 'Male') }}
{{ Form::radio('gender', 'male', ($teacher->gender == 'male')) }} 
{{ Form::label('female', 'Female') }}
{{ Form::radio('gender', 'female', ($teacher->gender == 'female')) }} 
{{ Form::close }}
```

And don't forget the `Form::close`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure with 4.2 but try

```
{{ Form::model($teacher, array('route'=> array('updateteacher', $teacher->id)))}}
{{ Form::label('gender','Enter your gender') }}
{{ Form::label('male','Male')}}
{{ Form::radio('gender' , 'male', $teacher->gender) }} 
{{ Form::label('female','Female') }}
{{ Form::radio('gender', 'female', $teacher->gender) }}
```

If that doesn't work try this.

```
{{ Form::model($teacher, array('route'=> array('updateteacher', $teacher->id)))}}
{{ Form::label('gender','Enetr your gender') }}
{{ Form::label('male','Male')}}
{{ Form::radio('gender' , 'male', ($teacher->gender==true)?1:0) }} 
{{ Form::label('female','Female') }}
{{ Form::radio('gender', 'female', ($teacher->gender==true)?1:0) }}
```